# How to specify two curves with different colors and shapes than all the others on geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

So i have a dataframe with 2 columns : "ID" and "Score"
ID contain the name of a simulation and each simulation have 58 different scores that are listed in the column Score. 
There is 10 simulations.

I am doing a geom_density plot :

```
    my_dataframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=`Score`), xlim = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = ID)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title = "Scores")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Csp5.jpg

How can i tell ggplot that i want the curves of Simulation1 and Simulation2 to not be like the others, i want them to be in red and with an higher width than all the other one.

Thank you for your help,

Best,

Maxime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
my_dataframe %>% mutate(group = ifelse(ID %in% c(1,2), 'special', 'NonSpecial')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=`Score`, lty = group), xlim = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = ID)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title = "Scores")
```

[image]

I used this data:

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(ID = factor(sample(1:4, 100, T)), Score = sin(1:100))
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for ! So the trick is to add a column to specify the simulations for which i want a special representation ! Thank you a lot for your help,